# change one format to another format of the array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, object

I have the main three parameters that are important category, subcategory, and group

This is an array of objects and I want to change the format of this array

Like all data divide into category inside sub-category inside group wise data I want

```
const data =
    [
        {
            "type": "checkbox",
            "value": true,
            "category": "id",
            "subcategory": "id document 1",
            "group": "group1"
        },
        {
            "type": "radio",
            "value": 2,
            "category": "id",
            "subcategory": "id document 2",
            "group": "group2"
        },
        {
            "type": "radio",
            "value": 3,
            "category": "id",
            "subcategory": "id document 2",
            "group": "group2"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "dfgdfg",
            "category": "Services",
            "subcategory": "Service A",
            "group": "g1"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "fxs",
            "category": "Services",
            "subcategory": "Service A",
            "group": "g1"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "3",
            "category": "Services access",
            "subcategory": "Service B",
            "group": "g1"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "sgredfg25ghfghrt54645dfeh",
            "category": "Services access",
            "subcategory": "Service B",
            "group": "g2"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "sgredfg25ghfghrt54645dfeh",
            "category": "Services access",
            "subcategory": "Service C",
            "group": "g3"
        }
    ]
```

The expected result looks like this

```js
const data = [
    {
        "category": "id",
        "subcategory": [
            {
                "subcategory_name": "id document 1",
                "subcategory_data": [
                    {
                        "group": "group1",
                        "groupdata": [
                            {
                                "type": "checkbox",
                                "value": true,
                                "category": "id",
                                "subcategory": "id document 1",
                                "group": "group1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "subcategory_name": "id document 2",
                "subcategory_data": [
                    {
                        "group": "group1",
                        "groupdata": [
                            {
                                "type": "checkbox",
                                "value": true,
                                "category": "id",
                                "subcategory": "id document 2",
                                "group": "group1"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "checkbox",
                                "value": true,
                                "category": "id",
                                "subcategory": "id document 2",
                                "group": "group1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Services",
        "subcategory": [
            {
                "subcategory_name": "Service B",
                "subcategory_data": [
                    {
                        "group": "c1",
                        "groupdata": [
                            {
                                "type": "checkbox",
                                "value": true,
                                "category": "Services",
                                "subcategory": "Service B",
                                "group": "c1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "group": "c2",
                        "groupdata": [
                            {
                                "type": "checkbox",
                                "value": true,
                                "category": "Services",
                                "subcategory": "Service B",
                                "group": "c2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "subcategory_name": "Service C",
                "subcategory_data": [
                    {
                        "group": "f1",
                        "groupdata": [
                            {
                                "type": "checkbox",
                                "value": true,
                                "category": "Services",
                                "subcategory": "Service C",
                                "group": "f1"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "checkbox",
                                "value": true,
                                "category": "Services",
                                "subcategory": "Service C",
                                "group": "f1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If the category match data push into the match subcategory if not then create a category for the same and if the subcategory match push into that one otherwise create a new one same as the group if the group match into subcategory then push otherwise create one

Like I want hierarchy like category => subcategory => group

And I try the this code

```js
let finaldata = []
let flag1;
let aa = []
for (let i = 0; i < parseData.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        finaldata.push({ category: parseData[i].category, subcategory: [parseData[i]] })
        flag1 = true
    } else {
        if (parseData[i - 1]?.category !== parseData[i].category) {
            finaldata.push({ category: parseData[i].category, subcategory: [parseData[i]] })
        } else {
            aa = finaldata.map(x => x.category === parseData[i].category ? { ...x, subcategory: [...x.subcategory, parseData[i]] } : x);
        }
    }
    if (!flag1) break;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you PLEASE share that?

Comment: I try the for loop but that only return the last match category only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this helps?

```js
const data =
    [
        {
            "type": "checkbox",
            "value": true,
            "category": "id",
            "subcategory": "id document 1",
            "group": "group1"
        },
        {
            "type": "radio",
            "value": 2,
            "category": "id",
            "subcategory": "id document 2",
            "group": "group2"
        },
        {
            "type": "radio",
            "value": 3,
            "category": "id",
            "subcategory": "id document 2",
            "group": "group2"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "dfgdfg",
            "category": "Services",
            "subcategory": "Service A",
            "group": "g1"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "fxs",
            "category": "Services",
            "subcategory": "Service A",
            "group": "g1"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "3",
            "category": "Services access",
            "subcategory": "Service B",
            "group": "g1"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "sgredfg25ghfghrt54645dfeh",
            "category": "Services access",
            "subcategory": "Service B",
            "group": "g2"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "sgredfg25ghfghrt54645dfeh",
            "category": "Services access",
            "subcategory": "Service C",
            "group": "g3"
        }
    ]

const result = data.reduce((p, c) => {
    const i = p.findIndex(p => p.category === c.category)
    if (i !== -1) {
        const j = p[i].subcategory.findIndex(s => s.subcategory_name === c.subcategory);
        if (j !== -1) {
            const k = p[i].subcategory[j].subcategory_data.findIndex(sd => sd.group === c.group);
            if (k !== -1) {
                p[i].subcategory[j].subcategory_data[k].groupdata.push(c);
                return p;
            }
            p[i].subcategory[j].subcategory_data.push({
                group: c.group,
                groupdata: [
                    c
                ]
            })
            return p;
        }
        p[i].subcategory.push({
            subcategory_name: c.subcategory,
            subcategory_data: [
                {
                    group: c.group,
                    groupdata: [
                        {
                            ...c
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
        return p
    }
    p.push({
        category: c.category,
        subcategory: [
            {
                subcategory_name: c.subcategory,
                subcategory_data: [
                    {
                        group: c.group,
                        groupdata: [
                            c
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    })
    return p;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It almost like matches my expected result but there is a slide data change in the group if two group match same name then put into the same group

Comment: Data service B has a total of three data and I want only two groups g1 and g2 inside of g2 I want 2 obj but currently, the g2 group makes it two separate obj 
if groups match the name then put them into the same group not create another obj

Comment: @MeetMajevadiya i edited my answer. i forgot to `return p` when `subcategory_name` is found.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to group items:

```js
const data = [{"type":"checkbox","value":true,"category":"id","subcategory":"id document 1","group":"group1"},{"type":"radio","value":2,"category":"id","subcategory":"id document 2","group":"group2"},{"type":"radio","value":3,"category":"id","subcategory":"id document 2","group":"group2"},{"type":"string","value":"dfgdfg","category":"Services","subcategory":"Service A","group":"g1"},{"type":"string","value":"fxs","category":"Services","subcategory":"Service A","group":"g1"},{"type":"string","value":"3","category":"Services access","subcategory":"Service B","group":"g1"},{"type":"string","value":"sgredfg25ghfghrt54645dfeh","category":"Services access","subcategory":"Service B","group":"g2"},{"type":"string","value":"sgredfg25ghfghrt54645dfeh","category":"Services access","subcategory":"Service C","group":"g3"}];

const groupByToPairs = (items, key) => Object.entries(items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item[key]] ??= [];
  acc[item[key]].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {}));

const makeGroups = (items) => groupByToPairs(items, 'group')
  .map(([group, groupdata]) => ({ group, groupdata }));
  
const makeSubcategories = (items) => groupByToPairs(items, 'subcategory')
  .map(([subcategory_name, items]) => ({ subcategory_name, subcategory_data: makeGroups(items) }));

const makeCategories = (items) => groupByToPairs(items, 'category')
  .map(([category, items]) => ({ category, subcategory: makeSubcategories(items) }));

console.log(makeCategories(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where can i find documents for `??=`? i kinda get what it does, but i want to make sure.

Comment: @Layhout It's [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)